# How does kkfile cancel the black background under TXT preview

Tags: javascript

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzLnP.png)

I hope I can cancel this black background, but I can't find a suitable solution in the document and online, and people around me use it relatively little. If my friends have made similar demands, please help me answer them. Thank you very much.